# Routing Between Multiple Points Using Location Document

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-maps

Hello I am developing under OS7 using the BB 9930 simulator.

I wanted to know if you can plot routes between multiple points using the Location Document that invokes Blackberry Maps. I have tried specifying multiple locations under the `<getRoute>` tag but that shows only the route between the last two location points. I tried specifying two `<getRoute>` tags under the `<lbs>` tag but that still shows only one route.

Is there any way to show multiple routes using the Location Document format?

If not, then does KML support routing between known latitude/longitude values?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: tags were not showing up properly.